# How to achieve full dynamic breadcrumbs in vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

The breadcrumbs I want to implement are dynamic names, not breadcrumbs with fixed names that are looped out based on routing. The user generates the corresponding breadcrumbs by clicking on the things, and this breadcrumbs will have a deep level.At first I thought of adding # to the end of the route, and then traversing the entire string of routes to generate breadcrumbs with the corresponding name, but if I use #, I can only write in the same component, and change the value behind # by listening to the route switch. This will make the files on this page bigger and bigger. I want to know if there is a better way.
Below is what I do in the breadcrumbs.Although this way of writing completely matches my needs, it is not very flexible. Every time you add a #, you have to modify it again, and as I said above, the page corresponding to the route will become larger and more complex. I want to know if there is a better solution to achieve this kind of dynamic click routing. Thanks in advance.

```
<template>
    <b-breadcrumb>
        <b-breadcrumb-item v-for="(item, index) in breadList" :key="index" :active="!(item.name !== name && index !== 1)">
          <router-link
            v-if="item.name !== name"
            :to="{ path: item.path === '' ? '/' : item.path }"
          >{{ item.meta.title }}</router-link>
          <span v-else>{{ item.meta.title }}</span>
        </b-breadcrumb-item>
      </b-breadcrumb>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          name: '',
          hash: '',
          breadList: []
        }
      },
      created () {
        this.getBreadcrumb()
      },
      methods: {
        /**
         * eg: http://localhost:8080/charDB/CharDBManage#Power-Power#1-project%20A1#version%20a1#2#records
         */
        getBreadcrumb () {
          this.breadList = []
          this.hash = this.$route.hash
          
          this.$route.matched.forEach(item => {
            if (item.name) {
              if (item.name === "CharDBManage") {
                item.query = { bar: 'datasheet' }
              }
              this.breadList.push(item)
            }
          })
          if (this.hash.includes('#')) {
            let lst = this.hash.split('#')
            let hashItems = []
            if (lst.length < 7) {
              lst.forEach(e => {
              if(e !== '') {
              hashItems.push(e)
              let item = {
                name: e.includes('-') ? e.split('-')[1] : e,
                path: `${this.$route.path}#${hashItems.join('#')}` ,
                meta: {
                  title: e.includes('-') ? e.split('-')[1].replace(/%20/g, ' ') : e.replace(/%20/g, ' ')
                }
              }
              this.breadList.push(item)
            }
          })
        }
      }
      this.name = this.breadList[this.breadList.length - 1].name
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route () {
      this.getBreadcrumb()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the rule to construct a breadcrumb? If each part of a breadcrumb is a link to the parent route - then I do not understand why the pages will become bigger and bigger? You will simply use a utility function taking the current route and it will return all the parent routes. Complexity is `O(n)` depending on the nesting level.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I mean if each part of a breadcrumb is link to a parent route, many vue files will link to the parent file, it makes the parent file and other files have a great degree of coupling.  I don't know an exact name of each breadcrumb, it is generated depend on which part u have clicked. they are totally dynamic. I wanna know if there is a better way to do those dynamic things except put then link to one page.

Comment: Normally the array of routes provided to the VueRouter is static - therefore, given a route instance, you can always trace it back to the root of the array. The code that does the tracing (`$route.matched.forEach`) does not need to know anything special - so the only strong coupling is between a route name/path and its corresponding component. It does not matter how many children any given route has - you can always walk the hierarchy using the same piece of code.